# How to prove this equation?

Tags: power-series

$\displaystyle\frac1N\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}e^{\frac{i2\pi\mu k}N}=\begin{cases}1,&k\mid\mu\\0,&k\nmid\mu\end{cases}$

where $\mu=0,\pm1,\pm2,\dots$ and $N>0$.

I hope for the procedure in detail.

Comment: Do you know how to evaluate geometric series?

Comment: sorry,I don't know. I really need your help.

Comment: Its not written as a series...

Comment: @Integral, it is a geometric series.

Comment: It should be $N|\mu$

Comment: $k=0,1...N-1$, its a finite sum. Maybe its not, but this is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $N|\mu, N=r\mu$ (say),$e^{\frac{2k\pi i}N}=e^{2k\pi r i}=1$ for all integer $k$

If $N\not\mid \mu, \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}e^{\frac{i2\pi\mu k}N}$
$=\frac{\left(e^{\frac{i2\pi\mu k}N}\right)^N-1}{e^{\frac{i2\pi\mu k}N}-1}$
$=\frac{e^{i2\pi\mu k}-1}{e^{\frac{i2\pi\mu k}N}-1}=0$ as $e^{\frac{i2\pi\mu k}N}-1\ne0$ as $N\not\mid \mu$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: In the complex plane, these points are on the unit circle, so if they are evenly spaced, their geometrical average indeed zero. Think about what "evenly spaced" means in terms of $k$ and 
$\mu$.

Answer (score 2):

Use geometric series and the properties of complex exponential, you will reduce this expression to some fraction, then try with a divisor of $k$ and another kind of number. This proof is really easy by that way. Fourier